# Why Abstract=True dosen't inherit in Meta class of django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I we have this models in django:

```
class FotherModel(models.Model):
    # Some fields goes here! 
    class Meta: 
        # Some fields goes here! 
        abstract = True 
class ChildModel(FotherModel):
    # Some fields goes here! 
    class Meta(FotherModel.Meta):
        #s Some fields goes here!
```

When we inherit a field from the meta class of Django models, that field  appears in child meta class, **But this rule does not apply to `abstract=True`**.

I know that if this happens, no table in database will be created, **But I don't know how this inheritance didn't happen.** Please explain this process for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Model metaclass resets `abstract` in a model's Meta class. In [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance) document you can see:

> Django does make one adjustment to the Meta class of an abstract base
>   class: before installing the Meta attribute, it sets abstract=False.
>   This means that children of abstract base classes don’t automatically
>   become abstract classes themselves.

Also, you can see the source code of this process in this [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/98f23a8af0be7e87535426c5c83058e2682bfdf8/django/db/models/base.py#L312-L318):

```
if abstract:
    # Abstract base models can't be instantiated and don't appear in
    # the list of models for an app. We do the final setup for them a
    # little differently from normal models.
    attr_meta.abstract = False
    new_class.Meta = attr_meta
    return new_class
```

Answer (score 5):

Because of the concept and effect of some fields in meta section in many cases it doesn't make sense that the field is inherited by chidren.

It has been described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance)